# AWS Lambda- Go runtime vs Custom runtime difference

Tags: go, aws-lambda

As I have seen in official documentation and many tutorials, AWS Lambda functions using Golang are provided with a zip file containing executable binary.
I cannot help but wonder: after converting the code/ app to executable binary, is it even Golang anymore ? So why designate a Go runtime option, rather than using good old custom runtime ?

Comment: Related: https://www.capitalone.com/tech/cloud/custom-runtime-for-go-based-lambda-functions/

Answer (score 1):

> Difference between Go runtime vs Custom runtime

There is no difference between Go runtime and Custom runtime because under the hood, Go is treated as a custom runtime and runs accordingly

> So why designate a Go runtime option, rather than using good old
> custom runtime?

Because For Go they have already created a runtime `provided.al2` so that A Go developer can take advantage of this by choosing the provided.al2 runtime and providing the required bootstrap file.

and one important thing

Runtimes that use the Amazon Linux operating system, such as Go 1.x, do not support the arm64 architecture. To use arm64 architecture, you can run Go with the provided.al2 runtime.